# Why do Finder and du report different file size?

Tags: macos, finder, vmware-fusion, geektool, du

I am writing a [geektool 3](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) script to show the size of a particular VMware Fusion virtual machine. Such `.vmwarevm` "file" is really a packaged directory.

**Get Info** in Finder says the file is "52.91 GB". I run the following `du` command to get the file size:

```
> du -hs ~/Documents/Virtual\ Machines.localized/MY-PRECIOUS-7.vmwarevm | awk '{print $1}'
```

This `du -hs` command returns the file size as "49G". What accounts for the difference from what Finder reports?

**Alternatively**, I have tried replacing the `-s` option with the `-d` option like so:

```
du -hd ~/Documents/Virtual\ Machines.localized/MY-PRECIOUS-7.vmwarevm | awk '{print $1}'
```

This `du -hd` command returns the file size as "59G". What accounts for the difference between Finder, `du -hd`, and `du -hs`?

Also, this `du -hd` command produces no output in geektool 3. What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not an Mac OS X user but I read somewhere that Finder uses base-10 nowadays.

Could the difference be that du still uses base-2?

```
49.0 GiB * (1024^3 bytes / GB) = 52,613,349,376 bytes = 52.6 GB
```

(the small difference is because `du` is rounding to the nearest GB)

Comment: The base-2 version would surely be *smaller*, though?

Comment: @Phoshi - finder says 52.91, du says 49

Comment: Oh, right you are. I misread that second "59G".

Comment: Does anyone know how to write a script that converts du output to base 10?

Answer (score 4):

Also note that "du" returns the actual disk space used, whereas other tools will return the allocated space.  Where you have sparse files these 2 values can be quite different - I have a file that has 2 TB allocated to it but it is only occupying about 200 MB of disk space.

Comment: What command-line tool that displays allocated space in OS X?

Comment: `ls` will (as covered by Stephen).

Answer (score 3):

Nifle is correct.  `du` returns base-2, Finder returns base-10, and 49GiB ≈ 52.91GB

The -d argument requires you to specify a depth.  From experimenting just now, it appears if you give something besides a number for depth, it eats the argument you specified and behaves as if you did `-d 0`.  The 59G you're getting is the size of the current directory, not the size of the vmwarevm file.

Here is the experiment I ran:

```
[~]$ ls -d Code
Code/

[~]$ du -h -s Code
8.3M    Code

[~]$ du -h -d 0 Code
8.3M    Code

[~]$ du -h -d Code
 38G    .           <-- this is the size of ~/

[~]$ du -h -d 0
 38G    .
```

You might want to read the [Mac OS X du(1) manpage](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/du.1.html) for more information.